# iOS - Notified when wifi or network radios become active (not just available)

Tags: ios, iphone, networking

I am writing an app that needs to 'phone home' every once and while but **not at any specific time**. Therefor I was wondering if there is a way to **register to be notified when either wifi or cell radios become active (not just available)** due to other apps transferring data, then piggy back off these requests to transmit my data.

I might be misunderstanding the functionality of the iPhone in general here. But I always assumed the radio entered a low power (stand by or sleep) mode when it is not being requested by applications. I feel like **reachability.h/.m** would initiate a request to connect to a host (such a google.com) therefore waking the radio and wasting energy.

Has apple not provided a registration method that triggers when the radio 'wakes' and starts transmitting data so that another application could use this opportunity to transfer any pending data without explicitly waking the radio itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your app is in the foreground (running) then just make the network call.  Since the iPhone won't let you run in the background, then it doesn't matter if there is a call back like you describe.

In your app delegate implement the applicationDidBecomeActive: to make the call home.